# Ember best way to manage css and js

Tags: ember.js

I have a large php application that I am converting to ember.js. In my php application I used to have separate css and js files which was loaded when the specific routes get called. what the best way to accomplish this in ember.js or is there any other best practice for that. Right now I am loading all the js and css files in my index.html file.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/gumby.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pages/global.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=assets/css/tooltipster.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pages/about.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pages/admin.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pages/global_print.css" media="print" />
```

js files:

```
<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/router.js"></script>
<script src="js/account.js"></script>
<script src="js/message.js"></script>
<script src="js/user.js"></script>
<script src="js/inquiry.js"></script>
```

I saw this tutorial http://madhatted.com/2013/6/29/lazy-loading-with-ember and also looked ember-cli. It will be really helpful for me if people share what they are doing for their application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you can take two paths to preprocess your assets: minify, compress, uglify, etc.

- You can do it with the back-end you are using. As examples here, you have Rails using sprockets for its [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), or PHP's [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic).
- If you don't want to rely on your back-end for this task, you can opt to do it using any front-end build tool. There are a few here, the most popular option for [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/#asset-compilation) these days seems to be [broccoli](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli), which comes set up by default. Other choices could be [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). All these options involve using your terminal to build your application, using a configuration file as a central point (`Brocfile.js`, `Gruntfile.js`, etc.)

It's mostly a matter of personal preference. As an example, I'd probably go with Rails asset pipeline for small projects, while I'd use `ember-cli` and `broccoli` if I'd be working on something bigger.